# Do we say "cut / break / tear / rip it in 3 / in 4 / in quarter / in 5 / in 6 etc"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

We often say

> [break/cut/tear etc something in half / in two](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/half) (=into two equal parts)
>
> She tore the piece of paper in half.

However, let's say there are 3 or 4  or 5 or 6 or more people and we want to divide the cake equally between them.

Do we say "**cut / break / tear / rip the cake in 3 / in 4 / in quarter / in 5 / in 6 etc**"?

Comment: We cut the cake into X pieces, or we divide it by X. We don't _tear_ baked goods, except for a special kind of flattish bread with divisions ready marked in it, designed to 'tear and share'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, we don't say that - at least not in the same way that "tore it in two" is idiomatic.

The idiom "*tore in two*" is more a description of the *action* of tearing than it is a statement about the number of pieces. You could tear something in two, and then repeat the action to get 4 pieces.

Instead, we would probably say:

> I tore it into four pieces.
>
> I cut the cake into six pieces.

Alternatively, another idiom used with *precise cutting* into *equal parts* is to say it has been cut [x] number of *ways*, for example:

> I cut the cake six ways.
>
> I divided the cake six ways.

This isn't really used with "torn", as tearing is not usually precise and does not always result in equally-sized parts.